# Implementing Quicksort with double-type values

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I have to create a program that takes an input file of unsorted numbers and outputs another file with the sorted numbers using Quicksort. This program has run fine under multiple test cases using integers. However, when I change the array format from 'int' to 'double' my program has trouble sorting the values correctly. The thing that perplexes me the most is that it is inconsistent. For example, the input "5,4,3,2,2.1" works fine, but the input "5,4,3,2.2,2.1" causes a seg fault. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
void swap(double *x, double *y)
{
   double tmp;
   tmp = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = tmp;
}

int pivot(int i, int j)
{
   return ((i+j)/2); 
}

void quickSort(double values[], int low, int high)
{
   int start;
   int end;
   int k;
   int p;


  if (low < high)
  {
     p = pivot(low,high);
     swap(&values[low],&values[p]);
     k = values[low];
     start = (low+1);
     end = high;

     while (start <= end)
     {
        while ((start <= high) && (values[start] <= k))
        {
           start++;
        }
        while ((end >= low) && (values[end] > k))
        { 
           end--;
        }
        if (start < end)
        {
           swap(&values[start],&values[end]);
        }
     }
     swap(&values[low],&values[end]);
     quickSort(values,low,(end-1));
     quickSort(values,(end+1),high);
  }
}

int main()
{
   ...
   quickSort(array, 0, (size+1);
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework by any chance (because there's a tag for that)?

Comment: Show us the real code - the call to `quickSort()` in `main()` won't compile.  Why would you be doing '`size+1`' anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `k` should be a double here :)

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing several values at the start of your quickSort method that may need to be doubles. Specifically k and p. Also it needs to take a double high and low value as parameters.

```
void quickSort(double values[], double low, double high)
{
    int start;
    int end;
    double k;
    double p;
    ...
```

A quick audit through for data types will probably solve your problem :)

Comment: The pivot value most certainly should NOT be a double.